# Universal MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to implement filter in database driven webpage. Some of the option may not have to be selected some of them may do. Filter as you know can change. The question is, is there any way to build a general query like:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE name='$name', author='$author', pages='$pages', font='$font';
```

When once user might just want to choose all books from the particular author, but doesnt care about any other limitations. Other time user might want to get all books with the same name, etc. The thing is, can I in that case just pass NULL or something like that for `pages=$pages` if I don't care how many pages it will have, but I want to use the same query for other possible filters set by user.

Comment: just pass in the field name. `author=author` v.s. `author='$author'` and note that you're probably vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), if you're writing queries like this.

Comment: So you're saying that if I do set `$author` variable, the rest of the variables can stay just undefined? I frankly don't think so

Comment: no. but for every field that WASN'T selected in the search, just set the variable equal to the fieldname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT` is the universal MySQL query you're looking for.

As far as I know, you can't disable a specific WHERE condition by passing a null or something else.

What you can do though, is to remove the condition from your query when you don't need it. Meaning you will have to build your query dynamically depending on the filters you'll want.

Comment: I guess, dynamicly built query is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You'd solve that in PHP by constructing the query dynamically.

```
$params = [];
foreach ( [ 'name', 'author', 'pages', 'font' ] as $p )
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST[$p] ) )
        $params[$p] = $_REQUEST[$p];

$sth = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM database.table WHERE " .
    implode( " AND ", array_map( function($k) { return "$k=?"; }, array_keys($params) ) )
);

$sth->execute( array_values( $params ) );
```